# Drive.API.v3 Different Accounts username / password authentication

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

So I have a few accounts that have documents on them, and having to switch between them all the time is quite frustrating, so I wanted to have them shared so that I can just have a link to view the file (no editing or anything).

Problem is, now with v3, I seemingly have to add the Drive API to every account that I want to view, which doesn't work for me. It's too much of a hassle to go through ALL of the accounts, when I have the username/password for them all already.

Is there a way to have a list of all my accounts username/passwords and somehow query to get a token to view only of the files? Or is this completely not possible anymore with v3.

I can get it working fine but instead of username/password, I have to enable drive API on the account, copy/paste the credential/secret instead of the username/password, and it works perfectly. I can search through all the files I have 'found' by accessing and reading the files and AlternateLink's accordingly... I just would like a non-intrusive way for my application to do this.

This is written in C#.

Comment: When you say "Problem is, now with v3, I seemingly have to add the Drive API to every account that I want to view", can you expand. It's certainly not true that user-X needs to enable the Drive API for app-Y to access his drive files. He simply needs to grant permission to app-Y, which is kinda obvious and inevitable.

Comment: Well, I don't know of a way with v3 to use the email login and password to request OAuth2 token's. Everything I see requires me to add the Drive API to the account under the developer console, which is the step I don't want. It's like an extra layer of security, but if it's my account and I have the username/password, I should be allowed to request ready only perhaps.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've got your head around OAuth yet. Each application is owned by a Google user (you) who I'll refer to as the "developer". You need to register your app on the dev console and register your app as accessing the Drive API. You do this once and once only. Some time later, another Google user (call him the consumer for now) will want to use your app to access a Google Drive. It might be his own Google Drive (the most common case) or a different Google Drive (less common and so less well documented, but nevertheless simple to do).

Comment: So, the consumer does NOT need to go anywhere near the dev console. All he needs to do is to authorize your app to access his Drive. If your app will be accessing Drives other than those of the consumer (which sounds like is your use case), each Drive owner needs to authorize your app to access it. This authorization is unavoidable (obviously), but only needs to happen once. As for username/password, just forget they ever existed. The closes OAuth facsimile is a stored refresh token which can be used in a broadly equivalent way that a u/p would have (but with constrained privilege).

Comment: My tip for anybody doing g Drive for the first time is to separate learning Drive from learning Google OAuth. They are two distinct topics and if you try to learn them together you'll find yourself going round in circles. Learn OAuth first, ie. learn how to get an access token. Once you've mastered that, then go on to look at Drive using that access token.

Comment: sooooo, long story short, it looks like you need to understand refresh tokens which will probably get you where you want to be. Peter's workaround using shared folders can also work in some cases, but it is a workaround. imho it is generally better to grasp OAuth.

Comment: @pinoyyid I understand what you're saying completely. I am saying that I am not having multiple users accessing one account, I am saying I have one user (me) accessing many many accounts. :) So yes, I am trying to avoid doing exactly what you said, "You need to register your app on the dev console and register your app as accessing the Drive API."

I would have to do it with over 30 accounts.

Comment: nooooo. You only need to register your app once. Once it's registered it needs to be granted access 30 times. Having said that, I see from the accepted answer that your accounts are within a GSuite domain (your question didn't mention that) so the domain delegation to a service account is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can no longer use username/password via an API since the ClientLogin API was [shutdown](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/04/a-final-farewell-to-clientlogin-oauth.html) in 2015.

Using OAuth, each user can be prompted to grant permission to your application. They need do this only once.

Alternatively and if the user accounts are GSuite based Google accounts, then your C# program could use a single service account and impersonate any or all accounts on your domain (once given permission to do that by your domain administrator). This obviates the need for each user to grant permission to your application. You can read about how to do this in the [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) doco.

Another alternative may be to create a google group and make all 3 accounts members of that group. Then share a folder (view, comment or edit access) with that group and put all files and sub folders there into that folder.

Comment: I read that (GSuite), but this is more of a 'I have 3 separate drive accounts, that contain specific types of documents. I need to access all of them on my end directly, without having to enable the Drive API on the accounts themselves.'

Comment: @JeremyWalker I have updated my answer in light of your comments.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. You realize how hard it is to find this stuff unless you ask on Stack. I have been reading through docs for the last couple of days, trying to figure out a way beyond Daimto's code, but to no avail. Now I know why :) Thank you!